# Using a key to clean data in two corresponding columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a large data frame (6 million rows, 20 columns) where data in one column corresponds to data in another column. I created a key that I now want to use to fix rows that have the wrong value. As a small example:

```
key = data.frame(animal = c('dog', 'cat', 'bird'), 
                  sound = c('bark', 'meow', 'chirp'))
```

The data frame looks like this (minus the other columns of data):

```
 df = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                     animal = c('dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'cat'), 
                     sound = c('meow', 'bark', 'chirp', 'chirp'))
```

I swear I have done this before but can't remember my solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like to make it so that all "dog" rows in `df` have the value "bark" from `key`, and all "cat" rows have "meow", etc?

Comment: You could try `merge(df, key, by = 'animal', suffixes = c('_original', '_corrected'))`

Comment: @jdobres Yes that is exactly what I am trying to achieve. The real df has 6 million rows and the key has 800 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`. If you want to fix sound according to animal,

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(sound = sapply(animal, function(x){key %>% filter(animal==x) %>% pull(sound)}))
```

should do the trick. If you want to fix animal according to sound:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(animal = sapply(sound, function(x){key %>% filter(sound==x) %>% pull(animal)}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about relative efficiency, but it's simpler to replace the partially incorrect column completely.  It may not even cost you very much time (since you have to look up values anyway to determine that an animal/sound pair is mismatched).

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% select(-sound) %>% full_join(key, by = "animal")
```

For 6 million rows, you may be better off using `data.table`. If you convert `df` and `key` to data tables (`as.data.table()`) that will take some up-front computational time but may speed up subsequent operations; you can use tidyverse operations on `data.table` objects without doing any further modifications, but native `data.table` operations might be faster:

```r
library(data.table
dft <- as.data.table(df)
k <- as.data.table(key)
merge(dft[,-"sound"], k, by = "animal")
```

I haven't bothered to do any benchmarking (would need much larger examples to be able to measure any differences).

Comment: I believe a join was how I have done this in the past. I will give it a try and compare with the previous solution. I agree on data.table, thanks for the reminder.